# How can I simplify this MatLab code?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, simplify

I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of the inner for loop

```
for i = 1:size(VALUES)
    for k = 2:bins+1
        if VALUES(i) < Arr(k)
            answer_list(i) = find(Arr == Arr(k)) - 1;
            break
        end
    end
end
```

`VALUES` is a file with 100 doubles from 2 to 4
`Arr` is an array with 4 values, starting at `VALUES` min a step of 1 and ends at `VALUES` max
`bins` is `Arr`'s length - 1
and `answer_list` is a column of numbers `VALUES` long that hold the discrete value depending on the size of the `bins` variable.

Comment: Yes.Can you show example input and expected output?

Comment: @Suever I edited the question to add more info.

Comment: A [mcve] is best, which is not necessarily your full problem nor a written description of it.

Comment: Does this really do what you want? The `for i = size(VALUES)` will loop over `i` with just 2 values (1 and 100, or maybe 100 and 1 if it's a column vector). As Frank says - a written description of your problem would be helpful here...

Comment: @Justin yes you're right, I fixed it. And yes the program does what I want.

Comment: It is still recommended to specify which dimension of `VALUES` you want to use, either the rows (`size(VALUES,1)`) or the columns (`size(VALUES,2)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you look for (in comments are the references to the original lines in your code):

```
out = bsxfun(@lt,VALUES(:).',Arr(:)) % if VALUES(i) < Arr(k):
out2 = size(out,1)-cumsum(out,1); % find(Arr == Arr(k)) - 1;
answer_list = out2(end,any(out,1)).';
```

This replaces the whole code, not only the inner loop.

Comment: I don't think `bsxfun(@lt,VALUES,Arr.'); ` will work. Since `Arr` is only 4 ints long and `VALUES` is 100 doubles long. ( but this sort of answer is exactly what I am looking for)

Comment: @lokilindo, have you _tried_? it works for me... Besides, because both `VALUES` and `Arr` are vectors, `bsxfun` **will** work, as long as you keep them in a different orientation (i.e. look for the `.'`  on `Arr` here...). BTW, in Matlab 2016b you don't even need `bsxfun`, it's implemented in the basic operators.

Comment: `Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.
Error in file_name (line #)
out = bsxfun(@lt,VALUES,Arr.'); % if VALUES(i) < Arr(k):`

That's the error I get.

`Arr` is only 4 digits long but VALUES is 100+

Comment: Try this: `bsxfun(@lt,VALUES(:).',Arr(:))`

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. It placed the result on a single row, instead of a column, as my original did, but the solution to that was a simple `transpose` here `answer_list = out2(end,any(out,1))';` . This was exactly was I wanted to find thanks.